# I want to fine tune a query which is taking more then 3-5 hours on the database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, query-performance

I want to fine tune the below query which is taking a long time to run on the database. the query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.FIN_DIVISION_CODE,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.BUYER,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.BUY_LINE,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.FIN_BRANCH_CODE,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.BRANCH_NUMBER,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
  NVL(RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_DESC,RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_DESC_LONG),
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.ON_HAND_QTY),
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.COMMITTED_QTY),
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.COMMITTED_QTY_RAW),
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.DEMAND_PER_DAY_ECL_HUB),
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.INBOUND_RECEIPT_QTY),
  RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.BRANCH_STOCK_FLAG,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.TOP_200_ITEM_FLAG,
  SUBSTR(RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.FULL_ISO,3,2),
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.ORDER_PNT_XFER_PNT
FROM
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT,
  RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV,
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR
WHERE
  ( RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.DW_BRANCH_ID=RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.DW_BRANCH_ID  )
  AND  ( RSE.RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR.CALENDAR_DATE=RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.VALUATION_DATE  )
  AND  ( RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_ID=RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.PRODUCT_ID  )
  AND  ( RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.PRODUCT_ID=RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.PRODUCT_ID and RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.DW_BRANCH_ID=RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.DW_BRANCH_ID  )
  AND  ( RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.SSO_ID= '570000018'  )
  AND  
  (
   RSE.RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR.DAY_RELATIVE  =  0
   AND
   RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.BRANCH_NUMBER  NOT IN  ( '1167','2305','1581','3129','1075','1078','7995'  )
   AND
   RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.ORDER_PNT_XFER_PNT  >  0
   AND
   RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.LOCATION_TYPE_DESC  IN  ( 'CONSIGNMENT','STOCK','PREVIEW QUEUE','TAGGED'  )
   AND
   CASE WHEN RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '0' THEN 'N' WHEN RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END  IN  ( 'AUTO','Y'  )
   AND
   RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_STATUS_DESC  IN  ( 'Stock'  )
   AND
   RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.FULL_ISO  IN  ( 'S.A','S.A1','S.A2','S.A3','S.A4','S.B','S.B1','S.B2','S.B3','S.B4','S.NA','S.NB','S.NS','S.S','S.S1','S.S2','S.S3','S.S4','S.T2','S.T3'  )
  )
GROUP BY
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.FIN_DIVISION_CODE, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.BUYER, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.BUY_LINE, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.FIN_BRANCH_CODE, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_BRANCH.BRANCH_NUMBER, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_NUMBER, 
  NVL(RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_DESC,RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT.PRODUCT_DESC_LONG), 
  RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.BRANCH_STOCK_FLAG, 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.TOP_200_ITEM_FLAG, 
  SUBSTR(RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.FULL_ISO,3,2), 
  RSE.RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR.ORDER_PNT_XFER_PNT
HAVING
  SUM(RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV.DEMAND_PER_DAY_ECL_HUB)  >  0;
```

Following is the explain plan:

```
Plan hash value: 2631612456

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |                             |     1 |   215 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:59 |       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                   |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                           |                             |     1 |   215 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:59 |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                           |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                          |                             |     1 |   215 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:59 |       |       |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |     1 |   116 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:59 |       |       |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |     1 |    97 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:59 |       |       |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                          |                             |     1 |    82 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:58 |       |       |
|   8 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR           |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  9 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR_I5        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  10 |         NESTED LOOPS                      |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  11 |          NESTED LOOPS                     |                             |   173 | 11937 |   479K  (1)| 01:35:58 |       |       |
|  12 |           INLIST ITERATOR                 |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|* 13 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR |   147 |  4263 | 48731   (1)| 00:09:45 |       |       |
|* 14 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN              | RSE_CD_D_PROD_BRANC_CUR_I2  |   208K|       |   602   (1)| 00:00:08 |       |       |
|  15 |           PARTITION RANGE ALL             |                             |     1 |       |  2932   (1)| 00:00:36 |     1 |  1465 |
|* 16 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN               | RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_I5       |     1 |       |  2932   (1)| 00:00:36 |     1 |  1465 |
|* 17 |          TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| RSE_IV_F_VALUATION          |     1 |    40 |  2933   (1)| 00:00:36 |     1 |     1 |
|* 18 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | RSE_IV_D_SECURITY_BRANCH    |     1 |    15 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 19 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | RSE_IV_D_SECURITY_BRANCH_I2 |   580 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 20 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | RSE_CD_D_BRANCH             |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 21 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | RSE_CD_D_BRANCH_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 22 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | RSE_CD_PRODUCT_FLAT_PK      |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|* 23 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT       |     1 |    99 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SUM("A"."DEMAND_PER_DAY_ECL_HUB")>0)
   7 - access("RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR"."CALENDAR_DATE"="A"."VALUATION_DATE")
   9 - access("RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR"."DAY_RELATIVE"=0)
  13 - filter("RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."ORDER_PNT_XFER_PNT">0 AND (CASE "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."BASE_STOCK_FLAG" 
              WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END ='AUTO' OR CASE "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' 
              THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END ='Y'))
  14 - access("RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.A' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.A1' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.A2' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.A3' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.A4' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.B' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.B1' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.B2' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.B3' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.B4' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.NA' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.NB' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.NS' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.S' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.S1' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.S2' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.S3' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.S4' OR 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.T2' OR "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."FULL_ISO"='S.T3')
  16 - access("RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."DW_BRANCH_ID"="A"."DW_BRANCH_ID" AND 
              "RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR"."PRODUCT_ID"="A"."PRODUCT_ID")
  17 - filter("A"."LOCATION_TYPE_DESC"='CONSIGNMENT' OR "A"."LOCATION_TYPE_DESC"='PREVIEW QUEUE' OR 
              "A"."LOCATION_TYPE_DESC"='STOCK' OR "A"."LOCATION_TYPE_DESC"='TAGGED')
  18 - filter("B"."SSO_ID"='570000018')
  19 - access("A"."DW_BRANCH_ID"="B"."DW_BRANCH_ID")
  20 - filter("RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'1167' AND "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'2305' AND 
              "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'1581' AND "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'3129' AND 
              "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'1075' AND "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'1078' AND 
              "RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUMBER"<>'7995')
  21 - access("RSE_CD_D_BRANCH"."DW_BRANCH_ID"="A"."DW_BRANCH_ID")
  22 - access("RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT"."PRODUCT_ID"="A"."PRODUCT_ID")
  23 - filter("RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_FLAT"."PRODUCT_STATUS_DESC"='Stock')
```

There is no index on valuation date but there are partitions on the date and i am unable to find what else i can do so that the query takes lesser time

Comment: the query accesses ALL partitions of parititoned table RSE_IV_F_VALUATION. I do not know the purpose of this query, but is it really necessay to access all partitions? By which colum is this table partitioned? Maybe the query by purpose must access all the partitions - but maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an [expression statistic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm#BEICJCJH) might significantly improve the cardinality estimate for the `CASE` predicate, which would then lead to other improvements in the explain plan.

---

**Finding the real problem**

First you should verify where the real problem is.  You know the query is slow, but what *operation* of the query is slow?  A tool like Real-Time SQL Monitoring
 will quickly answer that question.  Run a statement like `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your sql_id', type => 'text';`.  Look at the Activity % to see which step is taking the longest.

I would guess you will also see a huge difference between Estimated Rows and Actual Rows for Plan ID 13.  The column is a "flag", which I assume is returning way more then the estimated 147 rows.  That small estimate then leads to `NESTED LOOPS` instead of `HASH JOINS`.  Fixing that original cardinality problem may fix other problems.

**Sample schema and bad cardinality estimate**

The code below creates a skewed flag column.

```
--drop table RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR;
create table RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR(BASE_STOCK_FLAG varchar2(100));
insert into RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR select '0' from dual connect by level <= 10;
insert into RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR select '1' from dual connect by level <= 5000;
insert into RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR select '2' from dual connect by level <= 5000;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR');
end;
/
```

The query below returns 10,000 rows.  But the optimizer thinks it will only return 199.

```
explain plan for
select *
from RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '0' THEN 'N'
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'AUTO'
    END IN ( 'AUTO','Y'  );

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1579167612

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                             |   199 |   398 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR |   199 |   398 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='AUTO' OR CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='Y')
```

**Create expression statistic**

Use the predicate in the explain plan to generate an expression statistics.  This is like creating a separate column with just the results that will be filtered, and allows Oracle to make a much better estimate.

```
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(user, 'RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR', q'{(CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END)}')
from dual;

SYS_STU23HKS830RX09S$M3L713_6_
```

Now re-gather statistics and the estimate is much closer - 6673 rows instead of 199.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR');
end;
/

explain plan for
select *
from RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '0' THEN 'N'
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'AUTO'
    END IN ( 'AUTO','Y'  );

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1579167612

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                             |  6673 | 33365 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR |  6673 | 33365 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='AUTO' OR CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='Y')
```

**Once more for the histogram.**

You may have to re-run the SELECT statement and re-gather statistics again to generate a histogram. The histogram may provide even better results.  Re-running is necessary  because Oracle does not gather histograms on columns that have not been useful before.  (This makes sense when you think of all the audit columns that you don't need histograms for.)

Now the estimate is a perfect 10,000 rows.

```
select *
from RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '0' THEN 'N'
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'AUTO'
    END IN ( 'AUTO','Y'  );

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR');
end;
/

explain plan for
select *
from RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '0' THEN 'N'
        WHEN BASE_STOCK_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'AUTO'
    END IN ( 'AUTO','Y'  );

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);



Plan hash value: 1579167612

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                             | 10000 | 50000 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| RSE_CD_D_PRODUCT_BRANCH_CUR | 10000 | 50000 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='AUTO' OR CASE "BASE_STOCK_FLAG" WHEN '0' THEN 'N' WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'AUTO' END 
              ='Y')
```

**Applying this in your environment.**

You may have to play around with the expression to get it just right.  I'm not sure exactly how Oracle matches expressions with real predicates.  It may be necessary to add your schema name to the expression.

Comment: I dont have rights on the database to get the statistics. Although for the  Rows for Plan ID 13 as you said it is showing 'TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID'. I checked on db there is not index on 'BASE_STOCK_FLAG' then what index is it referring to. Also then i run the above queries it shows full table access so why is it not using indexes?

Comment: Plan ID 14 accesses the index RSE_CD_D_PROD_BRANC_CUR_I2 using the FULL_ISO predicate.  That operation returns a set of ROWIDs.  Those ROWIDs can then be used to quickly access the table in Plan ID 13.  Plan ID 13 also filters the rows based on the `CASE` predicate.  It's a little confusing because Plan ID 13 does two things - access based on a ROWID implicit index, and then filters based on the `CASE`.  In my simple example there is only a full table scan because there are no other steps or objects.  But the change to the cardinality should work the same.  (continued...)

Comment: My idea will not improve the performance of Plan IDs 14 and 13, but may improve the performance of other parts of the plan.  That's why it's important to use SQL Monitoring to find the slow operations, otherwise we're all just guessing.  To tune any statement you will need access to the database, your DBAs should understand that.

Comment: I tried applying indexs on all low cardinality fields but still those indexes are not being used. What might be the reason for index not being used? and how can i make sure that the indexes are used?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the main query as subquery and then join the additional tables:

```
(SELECT
  SUM(val.ON_HAND_QTY) sum_on_hand_qty,
  SUM(val.COMMITTED_QTY) sum_commited_qty,
  SUM(val.COMMITTED_QTY_RAW) sum_commited_qty_raw,
  SUM(val.DEMAND_PER_DAY_ECL_HUB) sum_demand_per_day_ecl_hub,
  SUM(val.INBOUND_RECEIPT_QTY) sum_inbound_receipt_qty,
  val.BRANCH_STOCK_FLAG,
  val.DW_BRANCH_ID,
  val.PRODUCT_ID
FROM RSE.RSE_IV_F_VALUATION_SV val
JOIN RSE.RSE_CD_D_CALENDAR cal ON cal.CALENDAR_DATE=val.VALUATION_DATE AND cal.DAY_RELATIVE  =  0
WHERE val.SSO_ID= '570000018' AND val.LOCATION_TYPE_DESC  IN  ( 'CONSIGNMENT','STOCK','PREVIEW QUEUE','TAGGED'  )
GROUP BY val.DW_BRANCH_ID,val.PRODUCT_ID,val.BRANCH_STOCK_FLAG
HAVING SUM(val.DEMAND_PER_DAY_ECL_HUB)>0) sums
```

Answer (score 0):

There is significant difference in the **estimated time** and the **actual time** taken for the query to execute as you mentioned. The estimated time shown in the explain plan is `01:35:59`, however you mentioned that the actual time taken is 4 to 5 hours. Which could be due to **statistics** being out of date.

**Gather statistics** on all the objects, and check the explain plan. You could do it at the schema level:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats('SCHEMA_NAME');
```

There are no full table scans, however the **index range scan** on `RSE_CD_D_PROD_BRANC_CUR_I2` is estimating `208k` rows. So, depending on the total number of rows of the table, you need to decide whether a index is really useful or not. Remember, **indexes are not always useful, and full table scans are not always bad**.

The documentation says,

> Create an index if you frequently want to retrieve less than 15% of the rows in a large table.

However, in practical use, it is way **less than 15%**. So, let's say if you are selecting more than ~20% of the rows from the table, **full table scan is much better than an index scan**. Also, as I already said, gathering the statistics up to date would help the optimizer decide the most optimal execution plan.

In short, it's all about **cardinality**.